# TypeGraphQL: ArgumentValidationError on mutation

Tags: graphql, typegraphql

I'm playing around with TypeGraphQL and have a simple api setup to query projects and their associated clients.

For my createClient mutation, I'm receiving an ArgumentValidation Error, 'an unknown value was passed to the validate function' and can't pinpoint whats going wrong.

**Client Schema**

```
import { ObjectType, Field, ID } from "type-graphql";

@ObjectType()
class ClientSchema {
    @Field(type => ID)
    id: string

    @Field()
    name: string

    @Field()
    email: string

    @Field()
    phone: string
}

export default ClientSchema
```

**Client Resolver**

```
import { Arg, Field, InputType, Mutation, Query, Resolver } from "type-graphql";

import exampleClients from "../utils/clients";
import ClientSchema from "../schemas/ClientsSchema";

@InputType()
class CreateClassInput {
    @Field()
    name: string

    @Field()
    email: string

    @Field()
    phone: string
}

@Resolver()
class ClientResolver {
  @Query((returns) => [ClientSchema])
  async clients() {
    return exampleClients;
  }

  @Query((returns) => ClientSchema)
  async client(@Arg("id") id: string) {
    const client = exampleClients.find((client) => client.id === id);

    if (!client) throw new Error("No such client"); 

    return client;
  }

  @Mutation((returns) => ClientSchema)
  async createClient(@Arg("data") createClassData: CreateClassInput) {
    const { name, email, phone } = createClassData;

    const newClient: ClientSchema = {
      id: String(exampleClients.length + 1),
      name,
      email,
      phone
    };

    exampleClients.push(newClient);

    return newClient;
  }
}

export default ClientResolver;
```

**GraphQL Query**

```
mutation createClient {
  createClient(data: { name: "Test Name", email: "Test Email", phone: "Test phone" }) {
    name
  }
}
```

If i pass the arguments to the mutation directly, without de-structuring an object, I don't get the error however with it I do. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: See [issue 1397](https://github.com/MichalLytek/type-graphql/issues/1397)'s [response](https://github.com/MichalLytek/type-graphql/issues/1397#issuecomment-1351432122)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `{ validate: false }` to your resolver, i.e.,

```
  async createTransaction(@Arg("input", { validate: false }) input: CreateTransaction) {
```

That fixed it for me, and I can still validate individual fields using decorators, such as `@IsEmail`.